# List of "used" Twitter hashtags

Tags: twitter

Does a list of used hashtags exist?

I mean: if I want to "create" a new meaning for a hashtag how can I search if anyone has used it before?

Comment: Why can't you just use Twitter search? If someone has used the hashtag it'll come up.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for `#tagname`. You can also navigate to `https://twitter.com/hashtag/{tagname}`. For example, going to  https://twitter.com/hashtag/jmm2010 tells me the tag was used by someone in 2009.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Twitter search as [suggested in another answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/76311/354), but I found a Twitter directory wherein you can also search hashtags:

http://twubs.com/p/hashtag-directory

I also think that knowing [who tweeted the hashtag first](http://ctrlq.org/first/) could also help you verify if it has been used. However, currently the site is down because it hasn't adapted yet to Twitter's new API.